# Create column in database based on the comparison of multiple columns

Tags: java, sql, database

I am using both Java and SQL for a database program I am writing (using Oracle Database). Suppose I have a table like the following:

```
Student         Major

 Student1        CS
 Student1        Math
 Student1        CS
 Student2        English
 Student2        Bio
 Student2        English
```

What is the best way that I can flag instances where the student changed from one major to the other and went back to their original major? Ideally, the output would look like:

```
Student         Major          Flagged_Values

 Student1        CS
 Student1        Math
 Student1        CS                 1 
 Student2        English
 Student2        CS
 Student2        English            1
```

Since Student1 and Student2 changed majors, then went back to the original. I am new at database programming, and the part I am confused with the most is comparing values from multiple columns, based on a student or id number such as my example above. If anyone can explain how to do that, it would be helpful.

```
String switches = "SELECT Table.Student, Table.Major, " +
            "COUNT(*)OVER (partition by Major)WHERE(partition by Student)" +
            "AS Switches FROM Table";
    ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(switches);
```

That's the code I have up to this point, but I don't know if partitioning twice in one statement would work, or if I would need a subpartition. If I wanted to add a new column with the flagged values, would I need a while loop to iterate through the ResultSet above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need a field to identify the order of these changes.  Otherwise there can be no concept of "previous".  For my example below, I'll use a "trans" field that increments with each student's change.

I would use two subqueries -- one to capture the immediately preceding transaction (to determine if this transaction is a major switch), and one to identify if the current major was applicable in any previous transaction.

I did this two ways.  The first only displays records that meet the criteria, and it shows the current major and the most recent major:

```
select
   students.student,
   students.major,
   students.trans,
   prev_row.major prev_major,
   prev_row.trans prev_trans
 from
   students
   join students prev_row
     on (students.student = prev_row.student
       and students.trans = prev_row.trans + 1
       and students.major != prev_row.major)
 where
   exists (select 'x'
             from students prev_row
            where students.student = prev_row.student
                 and students.trans > prev_row.trans + 1
                and students.major = prev_row.major);
```

The second table in the join ("prev_row") finds the student's preceding row (`students.trans = prev_row.trans + 1`), but only if the major is different (`students.major != prev_row.major`).

The "where exists" further restricts the result to only those records where a prior record exists with the current major.

Using sample data:

```
Student     Maj.    Trans
Student1    CS      1
Student1    Math    2
Student1    CS      3
Student2    English 1
Student2    Math    2
Student2    Math    3
Student2    Math    4
Student2    English 5
Student2    Law     6
Student2    Math    6
```

This will produce the following result:

```
STUDENT     MAJOR   TRANS   PREV_MAJOR  PREV_TRANS
Student1    CS      3       Math            2
Student2    English 5       Math            4
Student2    Math    6       English         5
```

The second approach I used will display your desired result:

```
 select
   students.student,
   students.major,
   students.trans,
   case when prev_row.student is not null
             and exists (select 'x'
                           from students prev_row
                          where students.student = prev_row.student
                               and students.trans > prev_row.trans + 1
                               and students.major = prev_row.major)
        then 1 else null end is_back
 from
   students
   left join students prev_row
     on (students.student = prev_row.student
       and students.trans = prev_row.trans + 1
       and students.major != prev_row.major)
```

This uses the same logic, but instead uses an inner join and a case when to display all rows, and flag the ones with a switch-back.

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72a3e/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an auto-incrementing primary key field named "Key", I think you can use a self-join to get the rows that represent a switch-back:

```
SELECT s1.Key 
FROM [student_table] s1
JOIN [student_table] s2 on s1.Student = s2.Student AND s1.Major = s2.Major
WHERE s1.Key > s2.Key
```

Verify that works for your data. Then for performing the actual update... shouldn't this be as simple as adding the `Flagged_Values` column and then running the query:

```
UPDATE [student_table] s
SET s.Flagged_Values = 1
WHERE s.Key IN
   (SELECT s1.Key 
    FROM [student_table] s1
    JOIN [student_table] s2 on s1.Student = s2.Student AND s1.Major = s2.Major
    WHERE s1.Key > s2.Key)
```